# ext js store/model example .net -converting php/mysql to .netwebservier/sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-services, extjs

Afternoon all,

I am working through a tutorial from MASTERING EXT JS and am stuck on retrieving data from db.
 The book has been using examples using PHP and MYSQL... which I do not know.  I use a .net web server and SQL, so I'm trying to convert this example from the tutorial, to how I would do it on my .net webserver.

the result in JSON format should be something like this

```
    {
 "data"[
{
"id":1",
"text" : "menu1",
"items": [
{"id": 2",
"text: "submenu2
},
{
"id":"3",
"text":"submenu3"
}
```

the php code they give me is this

php file 1

> $permissions = retrievePermissions($userName); $modules =
>   retrieveModules($permissions); $result = retrieveMenuOptions($modules,
>   $permissions);

php file 2

> function retrievePermissions($userName){
>
> ```
> require('../db/db.php');
>
> $sqlQuery = "SELECT p.menu_id menuId FROM User u ";
> $sqlQuery .= "INNER JOIN permissions p ON u.groups_id = p.groups_id ";
> $sqlQuery .= "INNER JOIN menu m ON p.menu_id = m.id ";
> $sqlQuery .= "WHERE u.username = '$userName' ";
>
> $permissions = [];
>
> if ($resultDb = $mysqli->query($sqlQuery)) {
>     while($user = $resultDb->fetch_assoc()) {
>         $permissions[] =  $user['menuId'];
>     }
> }
>
> $resultDb->free();
> $mysqli->close();
>
> return $permissions; }
> ```
>
> function retrieveModules($permissions){
>
> ```
> require('../db/db.php');
>
> $inClause = '(' . join(',',$permissions) . ')';
>
> $sqlQuery = "SELECT id, text, iconCls FROM menu WHERE menu_id IS NULL AND id in $inClause";
>
> $modules = [];
>
> if ($resultDb = $mysqli->query($sqlQuery)) {
>     while($module = $resultDb->fetch_assoc()) {
>         $modules[] = $module;
>
>     }
> }
>
> $resultDb->free();
> $mysqli->close();
>
> return $modules; }
> ```
>
> function retrieveMenuOptions($modules, $permissions){
>
> ```
> require('../db/db.php');
>
> $inClause = '(' . join(',',$permissions) . ')';
>
> $result = [];
>
> foreach ($modules as $module) {
>
>     $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_id = '";
>     $sqlQuery .= $module['id'] ."' AND id in $inClause";
>
>     // check if have a child node
>     if ($resultDb = $mysqli->query($sqlQuery)) {
>
>         // determine number of rows result set
>         $count = $resultDb->num_rows;
>
>         if ($count > 0){
>
>             $module['items'] = array();
>
>             while ($item = $resultDb->fetch_assoc()) {
>                 $module['items'][] = $item;
>             }
>
>         }
>         $result[] = $module;
>     }
> }
>
> $resultDb->close();
> $mysqli->close();
>
> return $result;
> ```

I'm trying to figure out how to return the same json format using my .net webservice/SQL instead of php/MySQL.
 It seems like it does 3 separate functions.  And the result array is used as a parameter for the next query.

The basics seem easy... like for retreivePermissions... it is a simple SELECT WHERE statement.
 retrieveModules seems to be an INNER JOIN with the first results.
 But the last one... retrieveMenuOptions, it pulls in both results as parameters, and It returns results.

That is what I don't understand... how can I pull the results from SQL in the same JSON result format.

Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example that uses a .NET Web API controller.  Not exactly a web service, but you'll get the idea. Check it out here:  http://jorgeramon.me/2015/ext-js-grid-search-with-net-and-mysql-backend/

Comment: thank you, I'm reading through your example but I think what I should have tried to explain is the tutorial in the book I am following gives me a nested result from MySQL... how can I achieve the same nested result from my sql db via .net webservice